# Jquery issue of triggers event multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have jquery script and when the page loads and I click the select box, it triggers one event. Now when i change the option from the select value, then i see the event is now triggered twice. Now again, if i change the option value, the event will trigger 3 times now. I only want the event to trigger once whenever I change the option value.

Please see the code below:-

```js
function myNewFunction(sel) {
     $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#qty-input').val("");
   $('#wasteCal').text("");
  
   $("#NoOpttion").click(function() {
   if (this.id == 'NoOpttion') {
   var a = $('#wasteCal').text("");
   console.log("wastage value = ");
    console.log(a);
    var getQty = $("#input-quantity").val(); 
    $('#qty-input').val(getQty || 0);
      onSkillCountChange();
  }
 
      $('#qty-input').keyup(function() {
   onSkillCountChange();
   });
 
    $('#qty-input').change(function() {
    onSkillCountChange();
   });
 
  function onSkillCountChange(){
  
   var str = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text ,first,second;
     str.replace(/(\d+) X (\d+)$/,function(str,p1,p2) {first = p1;second = p2});
      var areatotal = document.getElementById('qty-input').value;
      $("#areatotalt").text(areatotal); 
      var wastageCal = Math.ceil((parseInt(areatotal) * 0.10) + parseInt(areatotal)) ;
      $("#wasteCal").text(wastageCal); 
      var total = first * second;
      var size = (first + ' mm X ' + second + ' mm');
      var tilesizeFirstcm = first / 1000; // tile width in CM e.g 0.6
      $("#tilesizeFirstcmt").text(tilesizeFirstcm);
      var tilesizeSecondcm = second / 1000; // tile height in CM e.g 0.6
      $("#tilesizeSecondcmt").text(tilesizeSecondcm);
      var totalonetilecm = tilesizeFirstcm * tilesizeSecondcm; //this will calculate  area sq cm of one tile . e.g 0.36
      $("#totalonetilecmt").text(totalonetilecm);
      var boxperqty = $("#qtyperBox").text();
      var totaloneboxcm = totalonetilecm * boxperqty; //this will calculate  one box area cm . e.g. 1.44 . May required to add math ceil...
      $("#totalboxreqt").text(totaloneboxcm); 
      var totalboxreq  = Math.ceil(wastageCal / totaloneboxcm);  //this will calculate  how many boxes are required to do the project. e.g 9. May required to add math ceil...
      $("#totaltilesreqt").text(totalboxreq); 
      $("#boxesTotal").text(totalboxreq); 
      var totaltilesreq = Math.ceil(totalboxreq * boxperqty); //this will calculate  how many tiles in total are required to do the project . e.g 36. May required to add math ceil...
      $("#totalreqtilest").text(totaltilesreq);
      $("#tilesTotal").text(totaltilesreq);
      $("#input-quantity").val(wastageCal || 0);
      var qty = $('#input-quantity').val();
   var price = $("#basePrice").text().replace('$', '') ;
   var totalprice = qty * price;
   $("#tpr").text(totalprice); 
   if (typeof first === "undefined") {
    size = 'Please select the tile size';
     $("#tileSize").text(size);
    }
   else {
    $("#tileSize").text(size);
    }
   $("#totalreqtiles").text(totaltilesreq);
   }
   
   
  })
  });
     
  }
  
  
    // JavaScript Document for some other action
     
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#wasteCal').text("");
   $('#qty-input').val("");
   $('#input-quantity').val("");
  updateWastageAreaQty();
  
  
  $("#qty-input").change(function(){
    updateWastageAreaQty();
    
  });
  
  $("#qty-input").keyup(function(){
    updateWastageAreaQty() ;   
  });
  
   function  updateWastageAreaQty(){
      var value = $('#wasteCal').text();
     $('#input-quantity').val(value);
  
  }
  
  
 });
 
 
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#qty-input').val("");
     updateTotalPrice();
      
     
     $('select').change(function() {
     $('#qty-input').val("");
     $('#input-quantity').val("");
     $("#tpr").text("0"); 
     updateTotalPrice();
       });
     
     $('#input-quantity').keyup(function() {
      $('#qty-input').val(0);
     updateTotalPrice();
     });
     
     $('#input-quantity').change(function() {
     $('#qty-input').val(0);
     updateTotalPrice();
     });
     

      $("#qty-input").change(function(){
       updateTotalPrice();
       
     });
     
     $("#qty-input").keyup(function(){
       updateTotalPrice();
       
     });
     
     $("#qty-input").keyup(function(){
       updateTotalPrice() ;   
     });   
      
      
     
      function updateTotalPrice(){
      
      
        var qty = $('#input-quantity').val();
        
        
        
        var price = $("#basePrice").text().replace('$', '') ;
     
        var totalprice = qty * price;
       
        $("#tpr").text(totalprice); 
      
      
      }
     
     
     });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html dir="ltr" lang="en" class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html dir="ltr" lang="en" class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Avalon Gloss Subway Duck Egg Blue Tile</title>
<base href="http://www.thetileco.com.au/" />
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet"> 
<!-- image hover effect-->
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/hover-effect-image/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- image hover effect end-->
<link href="catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/magnific/magnific-popup.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/magnific/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/moment/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/moment/moment-with-locales.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- product zoom start -->
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/zoom/jquery.elevatezoom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- product zoom end -->
<!-- Sb Theme Custom javascript Start -->
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/sb-theme/sb-theme-custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Sb Theme Custom javascript End -->
<!-- animation javascript Start -->
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/animation/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/animation/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- animation javascript End -->
<!--counter start -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Counter-Up/1.0.0/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>
<!-- counter end -->
 <!--RTL start -->
             <!-- RTL END-->
<!--lightbox -->
    <!--    <script src="catalog/view/javascript/inspire/blog/lightbox-2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <link href="catalog/view/javascript/inspire/blog/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> -->
<!--lightbox End-->
<link href="http://www.thetileco.com.au/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=58" rel="canonical" />
<!-- product zoom start -->
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/zoom/jquery.elevatezoom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- product zoom end -->
<!-- Sb Theme Custom javascript Start -->
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/sb-theme/sb-theme-custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Sb Theme Custom javascript End -->
<!-- animation javascript Start -->
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/animation/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/animation/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- animation javascript End -->
<!--counter start -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Counter-Up/1.0.0/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>
<!-- counter end -->
 <!--RTL start -->
             <!-- RTL END-->
<!--lightbox -->
    <!--    <script src="catalog/view/javascript/inspire/blog/lightbox-2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <link href="catalog/view/javascript/inspire/blog/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> -->
<!--lightbox End-->
<link href="http://www.thetileco.com.au/image/catalog/logo/logo5.png" rel="icon" />


<!-- Magic Thumb OpenCart module version v4.4.13 [v1.6.73:v3.0.14] -->
<script type="text/javascript">window["mgctlbx$Pltm"] = "OpenCart";</script>
<link type="text/css" href="catalog/view/css/magicthumb.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<link type="text/css" href="catalog/view/css/magicthumb.module.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/magicthumb.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var mgtOptions = {
  'captionSource':'title',
  
 }
</script><script type="text/javascript">
 var mgtMobileOptions = {
  'slideMobileEffect':'rotate',
  'textClickHint':'Tap to expand'
 }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
               function mtOnDomReady(fnc) {
                    if (typeof(jQuery) == "undefined") {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            mtOnDomReady(fnc);
                        }, 250);
                        return;
                    }
                    jQuery(document).ready(fnc);
                }

                mtOnDomReady(function() {
                    jQuery(".hoverimage").on("click touchstart",
                        function() {
                            var newsrc = jQuery(this).attr("rel");
                            var arr = newsrc.split("!");
                            if (typeof MagicZoom != "undefined") {
                                MagicZoom.update(jQuery(".MagicZoom").attr("id"),arr[1],arr[0]);
                            } else if (typeof MagicThumb != "undefined") {
                                MagicThumb.update(jQuery(".MagicThumb").attr("id"),arr[1],arr[0]);
                            }
                        }
                    );
                });
                </script><script type="text/javascript">
                        var magicAddEvent = "je1";
                        if(typeof(magicJS.Doc.je1) == "undefined") magicAddEvent = "jAddEvent";
                        
                        $mjs(document)[magicAddEvent]('domready', function() {
                        if (typeof display !== 'undefined') {
                            var olddisplay = display;
                            window.display = function (view) {
                            if ("MagicThumb" != "MagicZoomPlus") {
                                MagicThumb.stop();
                                olddisplay(view);
                                MagicThumb.start();
                            } else {
                                MagicZoom.stop();
                                olddisplay(view);
                                MagicZoom.start();
                            }
                            }
                        }
                        });
                    </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var magictoolboxEvent = 'click';
                var switchDelay = 350;
                if(magictoolboxEvent == 'mouseover') switchDelay = switchDelay + 60;
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/magicthumb_product.js"></script>
            
</head>
<body>


       
       
       <div id="product">               <hr>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
               
                
                <tbody>
    
    <tr>
                  <td><strong>Product Code:</strong></td>
                  <td> Sample 2 </td>
                </tr>
               
                                  <tr>
                  <td><strong>TIle size</strong></td>
                  <td>
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#input-option235').val(0);
    });
          
      </script>
            <div class="form-group required "> 
           <!--   <label class="control-label" for="input-option235">TIle size</label> -->
              <select name="option[235]" id="input-option235" class="form-control" onChange="myNewFunction(this);">
                <option value="0"> --- Please Select --- </option>  
                                <option value="38">75 X 300
                 </option>
                                <option value="39">75 X 150
                 </option>
                              </select>
            </div></tr>
                </td>
                
    
    
    <tr>
                  <td><strong><span class="pp-titles">Qty Per Box <!-- Price in reward points: --></span> </strong></td>
      <td id="qtyperBox">
            <span class="spend-points-live">0</span>
            </td>
                 
                </tr>
    
     
    
    
    <tr>
                  <td><strong>Availability:</strong></td>
                  <td>In Stock </td>
                </tr>
    
           
          <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){  
   $('#WastageQuest').modal('hide'); 
   $('#input-quantity').focusout(function() {
    $('#WastageQuest').modal('show'); 
    
   });
   $('#WastageQuest').modal('hide'); 
    
   });
   </script>
    <tr>
                  <td><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
                  <td> <div class="form-group">
             <!-- <label class="control-label pp-price-title" for="input-quantity"> Qty : </label> -->
              <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" class="p-p-qty form-control" size="2" id="input-quantity" class="form-control" /> m² 
              <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="58" />
              <br/>             
      
            </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-loading-text="Loading..." data-toggle="modal" data-target="#WastageQuest">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span> Quantity Calculator 
        </button>
             </td>
                </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td><strong> Total Price : </strong> inc GST <br> (
            <span class="price-old-live">$56</span>
             Per m²)</td>
    <hr>
    
    <td>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                               <li class="product-prices"><span class="pp-price-title">   <!--      Total Price :  --> </span> 
                   <div id="tPrice"> $<span id="tpr"> </span> </div> 
                  </li>
                                                      
                                  </ul>
                    </td>
    
    </tr>
    
     
                  </tbody>
               
              </table>
     
   <!-- The Modal -->
   <style>
   
   .no-border {
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none; /* You may want to include this as bootstrap applies these styles too */
}
   
   </style>
   
     
   <div class="modal fade" id="WastageQuest">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Quantity Calculator</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
  
    <h6>Does your quantity already include wastage? </h6>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
    <button type="button" id="NoOpttion" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"  data-loading-text="Loading..." data-toggle="modal" data-target="#QtyCalModal">No</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

   
  <div class="modal fade" id="QtyCalModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Quantity Calculator</h4>
          <button type="button" id="btnClose" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
  
  <table class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    
    <tr>
     <td><strong>How many Square Meters do you need? </strong></td>
     <td><div class="sub-heading modal__block-number">
          <input class="form-control no-border" type="number" id="qty-input" size="5"> m² 
        </div></td>
    </tr>
    
     <tr>
    <td><strong>
    Tile Size</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
    <div id="tileSize"> </div>
    </td>
 
    </tr>
    
    
     
    <tr>
     <td><strong>Amount of wastage needed</strong></td>
     <td>10%</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td><strong>
    Area Total</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
    <span id="areatotalt" class="modal__block-item-right"></span>
    </td>
 
    </tr>
    
    <tr class="pp-price-title">
    <td><strong>
     Total Area needed after Wastage</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
    <span id="wasteCal" class="modal__block-item-right"></span> m²  required after wastage
    </td>
 
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td><strong>
     Box Required</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
    <span id="totaltilesreqt" class="modal__block-item-right">
    </td>
 
    </tr>
    
    
    <tr>
    <td><strong>
      Tiles Required</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
    <span id="totalreqtilest" class="modal__block-item-right"></span>
    </td>
 
    </tr>
    
   
  </tbody>
  </table>
    <div class="modal__block-item-left">You will need <strong><span id="tilesTotal">    </span> tiles </strong> (<span id="boxesTotal"> </span> boxes) to complete the project.  </div>
   
      
    
   <!-- <p> First Num <span id="tilesizeFirstcmt" class="modal__block-item-right"></span>
    <p> Sec Num <span id="tilesizeSecondcmt" class="modal__block-item-right"></span>
    <p> One Tile covers <span id="totalonetilecmt" class="modal__block-item-right"></span>
    <p> One Box Covers <span id="totalboxreqt" class="modal__block-item-right"></span> -->
 
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
             <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" id="button-cart" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</button>
            <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn btn-primary p-p-btn" title="Add to Wish List" onclick="wishlist.add('58');"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
            <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn btn-primary p-p-btn" title="Compare this Product" onclick="compare.add('58');"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
          </div>
            <!--multiple option end -->
   
    
       
</body></html>
```

Comment: This is too much code. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes get rid of everything that is not relevant to the specific problem

Comment: less code please.  also, there's a "tidy" button in the snippet editor.  it works miracles.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `$('select').unbind('change')` everytime you initialize a `$('select').change(...)` event. that goes for all other event triggers as well

Example:

```
$('select').unbind('change');
$('select').change(function() {
    ....
});
```

Comment: ACD , I have two select func events. but both does different results. so i have to put on both? thanks for the time

Comment: yeh sure. the first trigger will execute before it gets unbind before the next one. so no problem with that. it's just a fail safe for a single trigger event to be initialize twice

Answer (score 0):

`myNewFunction` adds event handlers every time it is called. It is called every time your input changes. Ergo, you will have one event handler per time you changed the input. Change once, 1 event handler, change twice, 2 event handlers, and so on. Establish your event handlers in a separate function, and not in an onchange.

Comment: Andrew, is there any way that when I change the options, it resets the value ??

Comment: Options where, value of what? That code is way too long to plow through it all: I just typed a hunch into the search bar.